# Find Folder/File location based on table values

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, outlook, email-attachments

I am trying to generate an email with a pdf attachment based on cell values.

Column F holds a confirmation number. Sometimes this is a whole number, and sometimes it contains a decimal.

The initial path will always be "C:\Users\mypc".
The next path should first locate the folder based on the country code in column K. It then needs to check the folders for the confirmation number from column F, but that value needs to be rounded down to the nearest whole number first, as the folder name will never contain a decimal.
Once the folder is located based on the confirmation number, it then needs to attach the pdf file inside. The pdf file will always match the confirmation number from F, before it was rounded down.

Currently, it cannot locate a folder if the name contains more characters (ex. The file name is '1234 Tommy 21 Feb 23').
It is currently directed to look at one folder (Mexico) but needs to reference column K to look for the country folder.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim sTo As String
    Set emailRng = Worksheets("POC&Airport Codes&KEY").Range("D3:D4")

    If InStr(1, Target, "BPS", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' Code for "BPS" condition
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "FRT", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' Code for "FRT" condition
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "PG", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' Code for "PG" condition
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "CP", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' Code for "CP" condition
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "CSC", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' Code for "CSC" condition
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "CEN", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' Code for "CEN" condition
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "AFI", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' Code for "AFI" condition
    ElseIf InStr(1, Target, "ATLAS", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        ' Code for "ATLAS" condition
    End If

    For Each cl In emailRng
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
    Next

    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Select Case Target.Column
        Case Is = 16
            Dim invoiceNumber As Double
            invoiceNumber = Fix(Range("F" & Target.Row).Value) ' Round down to nearest whole number

            Dim countryName As String
            countryName = Range("K" & Target.Row).Value

            Dim folderPath As String
            folderPath = "C:\Users\mypc\Mexico\" & CStr(invoiceNumber) & "\"

            Dim fileName As String
            fileName = Range("F" & Target.Row).Value & ".pdf" ' File name

            If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) <> "" Then ' Check if the folder exists
                If Dir(folderPath & fileName) <> "" Then ' Check if the file exists in the folder
                    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
                    With OutMail
                        .To = sTo
                        .CC = "CSREQUESTS@EMAIL.COM"
                        .Subject = Range("F" & Target.Row).Value & " " & Range("J" & Target.Row) & " " & Range("L" & Target.Row) & " " & Format(Range("A" & Target.Row), "dd-mmmm-yyyy") & " " & "CS"
                        .HTMLBody = "Please see the attached transportation request and confirm service at your earliest convenience.<br>" & Range("O" & Target.Row)
                        .Attachments.Add folderPath & fileName ' Add the attachment
                        .Display
                    End With
                Else
                    MsgBox "File not found for the invoice number: " & Range("F" & Target.Row).Value & " in the folder for country: " & countryName
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "Folder not found for the invoice number: " & Range("F" & Target.Row).Value & " in the country: " & countryName
            End If
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? What value do you pass to the `Attachments.Add` method? Can you determine the file manually?

Comment: I added debug logs to each part and  the only feedback was the folder was not located. 
Everything works exactly as intended unless the folder contains more information than just the confirmation number.

Comment: what's stopping you from just doing this? `folderPath = "C:\Users\mypc\" & countryName & "\" & CStr(invoiceNumber) & "\"`

Comment: Also instead of Dir, you can use [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) which lets you loop through Files and Subfolders, and you can check the names of the files using whichever VBA string operators you prefer. You could even create a Regex to compare the names against a pattern

Comment: @Toddleson I also tried that. I have 3 folders just to test. One as a whole number with a whole number pdf. 1 with a whole number folder and decimal pdf, and 1 with a full named folder (1234 France 12 June) and a whole number pdf. The last one is the one that still does not return.

Comment: @Toddleson I also tried this method. Same results. I also tried the left method as the confirmation number is the first part of the file name.

Comment: Are you saying the folder has a variable name?  A couple of complete file paths and some sample data will get you better responses.

Comment: The folder name will always follow this structure. 
"1234 countryName 12 June"
The number being the value from col F, the country from col K

Comment: Maybe `folderPath = "C:\Users\mypc\Mexico\" & CStr(invoiceNumber) & " *\"`  to be sure you're not detecting part of a different number eg "12345" will not match "123456" if it's expecting a space at the end of the number.  **Note** to build the full path you need to get the actual folder name returned from `Dir()`

Comment: @TimWilliams Based on the code being adapted per worksheet, this will not be an issue. I feel I am missing something as I have tried all these methods and only 1 case is still causing the issue.

Comment: When does ` 12 June" ` come from.  I don't see a date reference?

Comment: @TinMan It isn't reference from the sheet. The folder is created manually at a  separate time.  The code just needs to read the folder to see if it contains the confirmation number.

Comment: Is the filename from column F always unique?  Will there ever be a file in another folder in `C:\Users\mypc` with the same name?

Comment: There will not be. Every number in col F will always be unique. No file will contain the same exact number.

Answer (score 1):

Just focussing on the folder/file issue:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Const ROOT As String = "C:\Users\mypc\"
    Dim invNum, country As String, countryFolder As String, folderName As String, path

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'always 1 for this event?
    If Target.Column <> 16 Then Exit Sub
    
    'snipped...

    invNum = Target.EntireRow.Columns("F").Value
    country = Target.EntireRow.Columns("K").Value
    countryFolder = ROOT & country & "\"
    
    folderName = Dir(countryFolder & Fix(invNum) & " *", vbDirectory) 'EDITED
    If Len(folderName) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Found folder '" & countryFolder & folderName & "'"
        path = countryFolder & folderName & "\" & invNum & ".pdf"
        If Len(Dir(path, vbNormal)) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Found file: " & path
            '...
            'send the mail
            '...
        Else
            MsgBox "No matching file for " & invNum 
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No matching folder for " & invNum 
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Apologies for my lack of knowledge here, but should this do something?
It only returns a runtime error '52' - bad file name or number directing to "folderName = Dir(countryFolder & Fix(invNum) & " *\", vbDirectory)"

Comment: `Len(Dir(path, vbNormal))`  throws an `Invalid procedure call or argument` error because it breaks the `Diir` search.

Comment: See edit above for `folderName = Dir(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Using the FileSystemObject to check all the sub folder in `"C:\Users\mypc\` for the unique file name will simplify the process.

```
Function getCSRequestFullPath(FileName As String) As String
    Const RootFolder = "C:\Users\mypc\"
    ' Get the first folder
    Dim FolderName As String
    FolderName = Dir(RootFolder, vbDirectory)
    ' Loop through each folder
    
    Dim TestFileName As String
    Dim FSO As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim File As Object
    
    For Each Folder In FSO.GetFolder(RootFolder).SubFolders
        TestFileName = Folder & "\" & FileName
        If FSO.FileExists(TestFileName) Then
            getCSRequestFullPath = TestFileName
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: I'll keep messing with it. Looks like I'll just have to restructure my folders to make it work with the folder just containing the confirmation number since I can get that working. I'm not experienced enough to understand why this still doesn't return the correct information. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TonyMontez if the filename is in a direct subfolder of `C:\Users\mypc\`, this function will find the full name.   `getCSRequestFullPath("1234 Tommy 21 Feb 23")`.   If not consider adding a screenshot of the directory system.